# Private AWS Lambda API endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to set up api gateway endpoint for lambda functions to be only accessible internally ? I don't want it to be expose to the public.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit access to lambda or api gateway to a specific vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260555/limit-access-to-lambda-or-api-gateway-to-a-specific-vpc)

Comment: For those looking for accessing over VPN. Check this solution [how-to-access-private-api-gateway-over-on-prem-vpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246494/how-to-access-private-api-gateway-over-on-prem-vpn)

Answer (score 7):

API Gateway has released a new [Private Endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/) feature, which makes this possible.

The API Gateway [Private Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) will only be accessible from VPC and it requires setting up an [Interface VPC Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpce-interface.html) which will be used to access the endpoint. Also, it will be required to setup a [Resource Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html#apigateway-private-api-set-up-resource-policy) to grant access to the API from your VPCs and VPC endpoints.

In order to access the API endpoint from your on premises network, you can either establish a [AWS Direct Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) connection or [AWS VPN Connection](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/aws-privatelink-now-supports-access-over-aws-vpn/) from your on premise to the Amazon VPC.

Comment: If i set a private end point that is access through the vpc endpoint ... when the lambda is invoked, can it actually make http calls the the internet and receive a response ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. At the moment API Gateway Invoke URLs are public. Making them private is not possible.

You can secure your API Gateway Rest API using either [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html) or [custom authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now you can configure AWS API Gateway with private link. follow the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html), but you can only access the endpoint from VPC and if you want to access that end point from your data center you will need Direct Connect.